# Regex: Match this string

Tags: ruby, regex

I can't figure this out:

```
22.584\r\n\t\t\tl-6.579-22
```

I want to match the `"\r\n\t\t\t"` and replace with a single space `" "`. Problem is the number of `"\t"`, `"\r"`, and `"\n"` fluctuates, as do the surrounding characters.

Help!

Comment: What about ordinary spaces? Do you also want to replace two spaces with one space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>`s/\s+/ /g`</del>

```
s/(?:\\[rnt])+/ /g
```

Comment: @neezer, note that `\s` matches more than just `\t`, `\r`  or `\n`. It matches (in most cases) these: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`, but that may be fine with you of course.

Comment: @neezer: What language are you using?

Comment: @neezer: In what way doesn't it work? Does it give an error? Does it replace too much? Too little? Does it do nothing at all?

Comment: I'm using Ruby. It doesn't match anything. The values in the string in my question are not escape values (as in, to match, you'd search for `\\r` or the like).

Comment: Your edit matches them individually, not the group. I need to replace the whole group with a single space. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I think this is the correct idiom for replacing a sequence of whitespace characters with a space. It matches all possible whitespace, not just \r, \t and \n, it matched a sequence of one or more, and it does a global replace rather than just replacing the first such sequence. The only tricky bit is making the regexp apply to the whole string rather than one line at a time, otherwise you get left with \n's in your input.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP:

```
preg_replace("/(?:\\\[trn])+/", " ", $str);
```

Comment: did you see this was a ruby question?

Comment: When I answered there was no mention of ruby, or any other language. The post was edited later, as you can see. Also, accepted answer uses Perl's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\\[rnt]/ /g;s/  */ /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'22.584\r\n\t\t\tl-6.579-22'.gsub(/(\\[rnt])+/, ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

s = "22.584\r\n\t\t\tl-6.579-22"
p s                           # => "22.584\r\n\t\t\tl-6.579-22"
p s.gsub(/[\r\n\t]+/, ' ')    # => "22.584 l-6.579-22"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd treat the CR-NL as one atom:

```
str.gsub!(/(?:\r\n)+\t+/, ' ')
```