# Extra backslash needed in PHP regexp pattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre

When testing an answer for [another user's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145703/regex-match-this-string/2145740) I found something I don't understand. The problem was to replace all literal `\t` `\n` `\r` characters from a string with a single space.

Now, the first pattern I tried was:

```
/(?:\\[trn])+/
```

which surprisingly didn't work. I tried the same pattern in Perl and it worked fine. After some trial and error I found that PHP wants 3 or 4 backslashes for that pattern to match, as in:

```
/(?:\\\\[trn])+/
```

or

```
/(?:\\\[trn])+/
```

these patterns - to my surprise - both work. Why are these extra backslashes necessary?

Comment: Perl regexes are integrated into language, so you need only two backslashes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need 4 backslashes to represent 1 in regex because:

- 2 backslashes are used for unescaping in a string (`"\\\\" -> \\`)
- 1 backslash is used for unescaping in the regex engine (`\\ -> \`)

From the PHP doc,

> escaping any other character will result in the backslash being printed too<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)</sup>

Hence for `\\\[`,

- 1 backslash is used for unescaping the `\`, one stay because `\[` is invalid (`"\\\[" -> \\[`)
- 1 backslash is used for unescaping in the regex engine (`\\[ -> \[`)

Yes it works, but not a good practice.

Answer (score 8):

Its works in perl because you pass that directly as regex pattern `/(?:\\[trn])+/`

but in php, you need to pass as string, so need extra escaping for backslash itself.

```
"/(?:\\\\[trn])+/"
```

> The regex \ to match a single
>   backslash would become '/\\\\/' as a
>   [PHP preg string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html)

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression *is* just `/(?:\\[trn])+/`. But since you need to escape the backslashes in string declarations as well, each backslash must be expressed with `\\`:

```
"/(?:\\\\[trn])+/"
'/(?:\\\\[trn])+/'
```

Just three backspaces do also work because PHP doesn’t know the escape sequence `\[` and ignores it. So `\\` will become `\` but `\[` will stay `\[`.

Comment: Then why do 3 backslashes work? And why aren't single quotes different from double quotes in this case?

Comment: Gumbo:: just so I know if I understood correctly -- this case works because `\[` isn't a control character **and** it does not become a literal open square bracket because the pattern is parsed left to right so the backslash gets attached to the one preceding it and previously escaped?

Comment: @kemp: Yes, only the escape sequences listed in the manual are replaced.

Answer (score -2):

Use str_replace!

```
$code = str_replace(array("\t","\n","\r"),'',$code);
```

Should do the trick

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, and is also wrong because str_replace() doesn't allow substitution of all the requested characters (however many they are) with a single quote -- you can just remove them all.

Comment: @kemp yes it does. If it doesn't remove as it is try combinations of \r\n or \n\r

Comment: No, you can't substitute - say - three (or any arbitrary number) of those with a single whitespace, unless you want to provide **every** possible combination. What your code does is just removing them all.