# PHP Regex Expression isn't working. Issue with Backslashes?

Tags: php, regex, backslash

Regular expression in question:

```
$reg = '/[.]{1,}[\/\\]/';
if(preg_match($reg, $dir))...
```

I've tested this expression on http://regexpal.com and http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ it worked fine, but in my PHP script I'm getting this notification.

```
Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 12
```

I've messed around with the number of '\', but it hasn't changed anything. Any suggestions on what might be going wrong?

I've tried to look for similar issues, but all I seem to run into is people who haven't added delimiters.

Comment: Yeah, this one's kind of confusing. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2145823/1382779

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `\\` will be escaped by PHP to a single `\`, which will make `preg_match` evaluate your patterns as

```
/[.]{1,}[\/\]/
```

To have 2 backslashes in PHP string, you'll need to actually type 4:

```
$reg = '/[.]{1,}[\/\\\\]/';
preg_match($reg, "test");
```

Or use PHP's heredoc:

```
$reg = <<<REGEX
/[.]{1,}[\/\\\\]/
REGEX;
preg_match($reg, "test");
```

**EDIT:** seems like Heredoc also requires 4 backslashes. That's because of control characters like `\n`.