# RegEx - If Our Site URL Contains This, Then

Tags: php, regex

need some regex help for a regex newb.

If our URL contains

```
SearchBox.
```

(SearchBox with the dot on the end)   or

```
SearchBox-Empty
```

Then, we need to do something.  So example matching URLs would be:

http://www.thesite.com/SearchBox.html

or http://www.thesite.com/SearchBox-Empty.html

And a non-matching URL would be:

http://www.thesite.com/SearchBox-Function.html

So, I only want it to be matched when there is not a function being called.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if((preg_match("@SearchBox\.@",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || preg_match("@SearchBox\-Empty@",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) && !empty($_REQUEST['ID']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['ID'])) {
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Contradiction: SearchBox-Function contains SearchBox. Thus, did you mean either SearchBox.html or SearchBox-Empty.html (i.e. tld included)?

Comment: Well, specifically SearchBox.  with the dot on the end.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to check both `empty` and `is_numeric`. Any value which would fail `empty` will fail `is_numeric`, so `is_numeric` alone will do.

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you need to escape your backslashes:

```
"/SearchBox(?:\\.|-Empty)/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if(preg_match("/(SearchBox|SearchBox\-Empty)\.html$/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['ID'])) {
//...
}
```

Comment: op said searchbox can survive with just a dot (not whole .html)

Comment: may also imply that any rubbish can follow the dot and it will go through. similarly with empty.html

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work.  Just to make sure the rest of the code was correct, I changed it to just:

    "/^\/SearchBox/" 

and my "then" code worked fine, but using the regex above did not trigger the "then" code with this URL:

    http://www.thesite.com/SearchBox-Empty.html?&ID=58279

Thanks!

Comment: also seems to be that this regex will allow it through even if those 2 terms we discuss are deep in the request (I.e. not the pages requested themselves)

Comment: @CraigLillard No worries, I was hoping this guy would correct their answer... if they don't do it soon, I will post a competing one with those things I mentioned :)

Comment: @CraigLillard by the way, what IF they do put pure rubbish after the dot... (in the case of SearchBox.)..

Comment: In our case, it doesn't matter.  Still works fine.  Actually both your solution and the other streetpc's solution worked fine.  For some reason, we went with streetpcs tho.  Thanks to everyone for chiming in and helping out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex - I'm not too familiar with PHP regex flavour but:

```
preg_match("/SearchBox(\\.|\\-Empty\\.html)[.]*/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

Comment: Interesting about the issue of escapes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145804/extra-backslash-needed-in-php-regexp-pattern[/url]

Comment: Yeah, actually the double backslashes don't seem to work .  I had to use single backslashes to get it to work actually.  Ended up using this: /MediaBox(?:\.|-Empty\.)/  Used regex101.com to test it.