# Backslash in Regex- PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to learn Regex in PHP and stuck in here now. My ques may appear silly but pls do explain.
I went through a link:
[Extra backslash needed in PHP regexp pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145804/extra-backslash-needed-in-php-regexp-pattern)

But I just could not understand something:

In the answer he mentions two statements:

2 backslashes are used for unescaping in a string (`"\\\\"` -> `\\`)
1 backslash is used for unescaping in the regex engine (`\\` -> `\`)

My ques:
what does the word "unescaping" actually means? what is the purpose of unescaping?
Why do we need 4 backslashes to include it in the regex?

Comment: Its called escaping not ? Escaping is required because some characters are defined as preseverd characters with their own function. To let PHP know u want the real character, not the preseverd one u need to escape it so PHP don't treat like a special one

Comment: Then two backslashes would do the job, why are we including 4 backslashes?

Comment: Cause he wants \\ and not \

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash has a special meaning in both regexen *and* PHP. In both cases it is used as an escape character. For example, if you want to write a literal quote character inside a PHP string literal, this won't work:

```
$str = ''';
```

PHP would get "confused" which `'` ends the string and which is part of the string. That's where `\` comes in:

```
$str = '\'';
```

It *escapes* the special meaning of `'`, so instead of terminating the string literal, it is now just a normal character in the string. There are more escape sequences like `\n` as well.

This now means that `\` is a special character with a special meaning. To escape this conundrum when you want to write a literal `\`, you'll have to escape literal backslashes as `\\`:

```
$str = '\\'; // string literal representing one backslash
```

This works the same in both PHP and regexen. If you want to write a literal backslash in a regex, you have to write `/\\/`. Now, since you're writing your regexen as PHP strings, you need to double escape them:

```
$regex = '/\\\\/';
```

One pair of `\\` is first reduced to one `\` by the PHP string escaping mechanism, so the actual regex is `/\\/`, which is a regex which means "one backslash".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "preg_quote()":

http://php.net/preg_quote

This function escapes special chars, so you can give an input as it is, without escaping by yourself:

```
<?php
$string = "online 24/7. Only for \o/";
$escaped_string = preg_quote($string, "/"); // 2nd param is optional and used if you want to escape also the delimiter of your regex
echo $escaped_string; // $escaped_string: "online 24\/7.  Only for \\o\/"
?>
```