# How to replace "\\" in a URL using regex?

Tags: php, regex

```
$tag_path = "c:\work\link2\\tmp\\5699\\tables";
```

I want to delete **only the last** `\\tables` in `$tag_path`.

I used the code below:

```
$tag_path = preg_replace("/\\\\tables$/i", "", $tag_path);
```

But it returned the following result:

```
c:\work\link2\\tmp\\5699\
```

Why? How can I delete the last `\\tables` in `$tag_path`?

If i echo `tag_path="c:\work\link2\tmp\5699"`, But i write log `tag_path="c:\work\link2\\tmp\\5699\"`

Comment: Use `str_replace()` instead: `str_replace('\\tables', '', $tag_path);`.

Comment: I only want to delete last '\\tables'. If tag_path has 2  '\\tables'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extra backslash needed in PHP regexp pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145804/extra-backslash-needed-in-php-regexp-pattern)

Comment: @user1497597: I'm not sure how it doesn't work. See [this demo](https://eval.in/147602). Your `preg_replace` statement works as it should.

Comment: have not answer correct

Comment: I think your pattern is produce as you want

Comment: @user1497597: What do you mean by "*have not answer correct*"? Please clarify.

Comment: No mean, i say : possible duplicate of Extra backslash needed in PHP regexp pattern –  Anonymous 3

Comment: @AmalMurali If i echo tag_path="c:\work\link2\tmp\5699", But i write log tag_path="c:\work\link2\\tmp\\5699\"

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
str_replace('\\tables', '', $tag_path);
```

... should do the job. Note that I'm using single quotes and I'm using `str_replace()` in favour of `preg_replace()` because you are about to replace a constant pattern, no regex. In this case `str_replace()` is simpler and therefore faster.

---

**Update**:

In comments you told that you want to replace `\\tables` only if it is the end of the path. Then a regex is the right solution. Use this one:

```
preg_replace('~\\\\tables$~', '', $tag_path);
```

Also here the single quotes do the trick. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20819109/1438393) which explains that nicely. Furthermore I'm using `~` as the pattern delimiter for more clearness.

Comment: I only delete last '\\tables'

Comment: Nitpick: This wouldn't still work. To match a literal backslash, you'd have to write ``\\\\``. (As for why, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20819109/1438393).) ;-)

Comment: @AmalMurali Hey, thx!. wouldn't have expected that. But sounds logic now :)

Comment: If i echo tag_path="c:\work\link2\tmp\5699", But i write log tag_path="c:\work\link2\\tmp\\5699\"

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strrpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) as a lookbehind for the last `\\`. (*No strict rule*)

This even works if your `tables` is `TABLES` , `tab` or any other data after the last `\\`

```
echo substr($tag_path,0,strrpos($tag_path,'\\'));
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/147603)</kbd>

Comment: If i echo tag_path="c:\work\link2\tmp\5699", But i write log tag_path="c:\work\link2\\tmp\\5699\"

Comment: @user1497597, It's easy add a slash at the end. See this [**demo**](https://eval.in/147932)

Comment: No, I use code: substr($tag_path,0,strrpos($tag_path,'\\')); if i write log result still: tag_path="c:\work\link2\\tmp\\5699\"

Comment: If i use echo tag_path="c:\work\link2\tmp\5699", But i write log tag_path="c:\work\link2\\tmp\\5699\". I echo result the same demo. But write log, it still error.

Comment: What is your expected output ?